# What is the purpose of the two 1N4148 diodes used in this circuit?

Tags: diodes

What is the purpose of the two 1N4148 diodes used in this circuit?

[image]

Regards

Edit:Source page of the circuit..

http://www.radanpro.com/Radan2400/Video/TV%20remote%20control%20blocker-jammer%20circuit%20diagram.htm

Comment: Sure ...i don't know what this circuit do... I found it while searching about it circuit ^^

Answer (score 29):

When pin 3 of the timer is low, the voltage at the base of the transistor is about 1.4 V below Vcc, and therefore the voltage across the 180 \$\Omega\$ resistor is around 0.7 V. So the current through the transistor and LED's is about 3.9 mA, regardless of variations in supply voltage (which I guess is a 9 V battery, and can vary a lot). Hence the LED's should stay at the same brightness for a wide range of supply voltage.

In a few words - it's a current source circuit. (Good one to memorize, it comes up a lot. The other common way is to use a zener instead of the two diodes.)

Comment: +1 A variation is to replace the two series diodes (~1.4V) with a red LED (~1.8V), which gives you an indicator LED for free.